# How to remove n-numbers of characters after a certain pattern using sed or awk?

Tags: awk, sed

Let's say I have a file with lines look like this:

```
12:03:22.141245532 12:03:22.892612543 my_script_bla_bla
```

I need to make all the lines of the file look like this:

```
12:03:22.1 12:03:22.8 my_script_bla_bla
```

How can I achieve it using awk or sed?

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: [edit] your question to state what `a certain pattern` is and what `n` is in `n-numbers of characters`. Don't assume we can guess your requirements from 1 sample input.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `gnu awk` command:

```sh
awk '{for (i=1; i<=2; ++i) $i=gensub(/(\.[0-9])[0-9]+$/, "\\1", "1", $i)} 1' file

12:03:22.1 12:03:22.8 my_script_bla_bla
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/^\([0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9]\)[0-9]* \([0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9]\)[0-9]*/\1 \2/'
```

Match two time strings, capturing the information up to and including the first digit after the decimal point, ignoring any extra digits, replacing the input with the two captured strings.

It's not very compact.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` `gensub` following way, let file.txt content be:

```
12:03:22.141245532 12:03:22.892612543 my_script_bla_bla
```

then

```
awk '{print gensub(/([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9])[0-9]+/, "\\1", "g")}' file.txt
```

output

```
12:03:22.1 12:03:22.8 my_script_bla_bla
```

Explanation: I used single capturing group enclosing characters to be preserved and global (`g`) mode of `gensub`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed ):

```
sed -E 's/(..:..:..\..)\S+/\1/g' file
```

Pattern match a date and time and remove most of the time.

N.B. This will probably work but if you want belt-and-braces use:

```
sed -E 's/^([[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]])[[:digit:]]* ([[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}\.[[:digit:]])[[:digit:]]*/\1 \2/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{$1=substr($1,1,10);$2=substr($2,1,10)}1' file

12:03:22.1 12:03:22.8 my_script_bla_bla
```

looks like a timestamp formatted data; trim the first two fields after the 10'th char.

Answer (score -1):

Using Perl

```
$ echo "12:03:22.141245532 12:03:22.892612543 my_script_bla_bla" | perl -ne ' s/\.(.)\S+/.$1/ ; s/\.(.)\S+/.$1/; print '
12:03:22.1 12:03:22.8 my_script_bla_bla
$
```

If the `my_script_bla_bla` doesn't have any ".", then

```
$ echo "12:03:22.141245532 12:03:22.892612543 my_script_bla_bla" | perl -pe ' s/\.\K(.)\S+/$1/g '
12:03:22.1 12:03:22.8 my_script_bla_bla
$
```

Comment: awk or sed were the choices.